# Transaction using strapi

Tags: mysql, transactions, strapi

I am learning to use strapi, and have a question.
How I do the database transaction like commit & rollback when using strapi & mySql ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a transactions as follows

```
await strapi.connections.default.transaction(
          async (trx) => {
                //functions inside transaction
                await trx.raw("insert into table..............")
          });
```